# What is the need for this step in this assembly code - x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Here is a program for the user to input some characters and it will output whatever the user types in.

```
    ; Section to store variables
    section .data
    string_msg: db "Enter a string (Max=64 Characters)", 0xD, 0
    string_in: times 65 db 0h ; max = 64 char, last ch=null
    string_out: times 65 db 0h ; max = 64 char, last ch=null

    ; Start of program
    global _main
    section .text
    _main:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging

    PRINT_STRING string_msg
    NEWLINE
    GET_STRING string_in, 65

   ; init value to process input string
   xor ebx, ebx

   start:
   mov al, byte[string_in  + ebx]
   mov byte[string_out + ebx], al

   PRINT_CHAR al
   cmp al, 0h
   je end
   inc ebx
   jmp start

   end: 
   xor eax, eax    ; terminate program
   ret
```

What I do not understand is why is the `mov byte[string_out + ebx], al` there for? What does it mean?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction that you are referring to (`mov byte[string_out + ebx], al`), is just making a copy of the inputted string.

Since the string is displayed one character at a time using PRINT_CHAR, the display doesn't  really need it.

If ever this program is expanded to use an alternative output method, then this copy might become just what is needed.

```
PRINT_STRING string_out
```

---

> ```
> PRINT_CHAR al
> cmp al, 0h
> je end
> ```

This could be a small error! The terminating zero should normally not be displayed on screen. The test would better be done **before** printing.

```
cmp al, 0
je  end
PRINT_CHAR al
```

Comment: oh gee thank you very much for your answer! It is very helpful @Fifoernik

Comment: Just one more question, what is the character stored as? is it stored as the hex code? if not how can i make that possible? @Fifoernik

Comment: @Bryan: Its ASCII code is stored as an 8-bit integer.  Hex has nothing to do with it, except as a human-readable way to display 8-bit values.  (i.e. the translation to hex happens in your debugger.  It's binary inside the CPU.)